# Помогите маленькую структуру данных "Клиенты Банка" написать

Tags: java, массивы, list, коллекции, динамические-массивы

Я новичок. Помогите маленькую структуру данных "Клиенты Банка" написать с id(тип int),name(тип String) и bill(счёт)(тип int) с возможностью добавлять/удалять запись динамически.

Comment: Помогите себе сами, если не получится, тогда спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Банальный вопрос - банальный ответ :D

```java
class BankClient {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int bill;

    public BankClient(int id, String name, int bill) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.bill = bill;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBill() {
        return bill;
    }

    public void setBill(int bill) {
        this.bill = bill;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        BankClient that = (BankClient) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (bill != that.bill) return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(that.name) : that.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + bill;
        return result;
    }
}

class BankClientList {
    private ArrayList<BankClient> bankClients;

    public BankClientList() {
        bankClients = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(BankClient client) {
        this.bankClients.add(client);
    }

    public BankClient get(int index) {
        return bankClients.get(index);
    }

    public int indexOf(BankClient client) {
        return bankClients.indexOf(client);
    }

    public boolean contains(BankClient client) {
        return bankClients.contains(client);
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        bankClients.remove(index);
    }

    public void remove(BankClient client) {
        bankClients.remove(client);
    }

    public BankClient set(int index, BankClient client) {
        return bankClients.set(index, client);
    }

    public void clear() {
        bankClients.clear();
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return bankClients.toArray();
    }

    public int size() {
        return bankClients.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return bankClients.isEmpty();
    }

}
```